# Subspace of countably compact space

Tags: general-topology

I know that: the subspace of countably compact space is not need to be countably compact, but i can't find any counterexample for that?!

Comment: can you please explain the definition of countably compact space?

Comment: Countably compact: every countable cover has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 1):

$(0,1)$ is not countably compact, although it is a subspace of the compact $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $X = \{0\} \cup \{1/n | n \in {\mathbb N}\}$ with the interval topology. This is compact but no longer compact if you remove $0$.